# Overflow Text Field to Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a question about syntax for handling text fields that overflow an arbitrary limit.

I have the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notes](
[Note] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Code1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Code2] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO Notes (Code1,Code2,Note)

VALUES
('JAD','XFR','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
('JAD','X400','Lorem ipsum '),
('JAD','X700','Lorem ')
```

My task is to make a query that will return all of the data in the table, but the receiving system has a character limit on the notes field (the real system only accepts 255 characters. I have shortened it here for brevity).

To handle that limit, what I need is when that notes field overflows the limit, the query should add another row to the output that contains the next portion of the note text, but the first two fields of the row should repeat the first two codes.

The query below accomplishes the task, but it is extremely ugly and has limitations. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution to a problem that is admittedly terrible.

Also, the receiving system is a client system. I have no visibility into why on earth it wants a data dump in a format this soul crushingly stupid, so please don't ask.

```
    DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
    RowNumber INT,
    Depth INT,
    Code1 VARCHAR(50),
    Code2 VARCHAR(50),
    Note VARCHAR(MAX)    
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Code1),
1,
Code1,
Code2,
left(Note,(5 - len(Code1) + len(Code2)))
FROM Notes

UNION ALL

SELECT
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Code1),
2,
Code1,
Code2,
substring(Note,(5 - len(Code1) + len(Code2))+1,5)
FROM Notes


UNION ALL

SELECT
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Code1),
3,
Code1,
Code2,
substring(Note,(5 - len(Code1) + len(Code2))+6,5)
FROM Notes


UNION ALL

SELECT
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Code1),
4,
Code1,
Code2,
substring(Note,(5 - len(Code1) + len(Code2))+11,5)
FROM Notes



UNION ALL

SELECT
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Code1),
5,
Code1,
Code2,
substring(Note,(5 - len(Code1) + len(Code2))+16,5)
FROM Notes



Select
Code1,
Code2,
Note
FROM @TEMP AS T
WHERE NOTE <> ''
ORDER BY RowNumber, Depth
```

Output should look like:

```
Code1   Code2   Note
JAD     XFR     Lorem
JAD     XFR      ipsu
JAD     XFR     m dol
JAD     XFR     or si
JAD     XFR     t ame
JAD     X400    Lorem 
JAD     X400    ipsum
JAD     X700    Lorem
```

Comment: I don't want to store it this way at all. This is just the code to generate the output for the client system. The only issue with using cr/lf after each 255 characters, is that will not  repeat the columns at the front, which in the production application contains identifying information, presumably for the receiving system to be able to put all this stuff back together.

Comment: Other than the 255 character limit described earlier, I'm not sure I understand the question. That character count is the limit I was given. Past that the field must overflow to a new row.

I think the substring function may be a point of confusion, and I'm not completely sure what the end limit will per row include, whether my limit will be 255 - (code1 + code2) or 255 + code1 + code2. 

But I think the essence of the question is the same with just a little tweaking of the arithmetic either way.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry, the field is VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Well, right now the largest entry is ~900 characters. Purely by chance. There is no real limit to what the user can type into this field. My guess is that it will be a while before anyone wants to enter more than about 1500 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH Note1(note, code1, code2, start, orig) AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Note, 1, 5), Code1, Code2, 1, Note
    FROM Notes

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUBSTRING(orig, start + 5, 5), Code1, Code2, start + 5, orig
    FROM Note1
    WHERE LEN(SUBSTRING(orig, start + 5, 5)) > 0
)
SELECT code1, code2, note FROM Note1
ORDER BY Note1.code2, Note1.start
```

I admit, my naming sucks :)

Comment: You will exceed the recursion limits (and possibly performance tolerances as well) if the Note column can really approach 2 GB...

Comment: Wow, that seems like a really good solution. I only have the vaguest idea of how it works though because I'm not well versed in CTE recursion. Could you summarize?

Comment: Ok, I so I figured out how this works, and I was able to adapt it to me needs pretty quickly in a way that people after me should be able to support it after me. Thanks very much for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start by bringing all your data into a staging table.  Then do a series of inserts into your real table and updates to the staging table.

Make sure the real table has the appropriate primary and foreign keys so that you can re-assemble the text afterwards.